# Using SAS, png files is convert to binary data?

Tags: png, sas, binary-data

I want to use the chart of SAS on Spotfire.

So I tries to create png file as binary data on SAS.

Is that possible?

I try to import the png file as binary data, but Sas did not.
On R, "read.bin"

```
 data test2;
infile "&filepath" recfm=f;
input value binary8.1 @@;
 run;
```

Please let me know.

Comment: Please can you flesh out the detail on what you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704958/sas-read-in-pdf-file) might be useful to you?